# How to pass data to another page without using this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, data) in ionic

Tags: arrays, json, ionic-framework, ionic3

Let say I have pass user login **username** as data to a php api url to fetch the user details from the database like this

```
let data = {
  username: this.username
     };
```

`this.http.post('http://onitor.com/api/retrieve_data.php',data, options)`

When the data returns back in a json format,

```
.map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
   loader.dismiss()
    this.items=res.server_response;
    console.log(this.items);
    });
    });
```

I want to pass those data to **PostPage** and i don't want to use a push methode like this

```
this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, data);
```

How can I do it? I'm not yet familiar with ionic.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a storage then get it to the other page?

Comment: @Mystery, I don't know how to do that: reason for my question on how I can do it.

Comment: Did you try following docs? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction depending on your case there are a number of methods to do what yiu want

Answer (score 1):

You can use service. Write http request code in that service and return data using Promise. Also declare global variable in service and access it anywhere throughout application,

In your service.ts file,

```
data: any;

retrieveData(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post("http://onitor.com/api/retrieve_data.php", data)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
}  

getData(){
  return this.data;
}
```

In your component.ts,

```
postData(){
    let postParams = {

    }
    this.myService.retrieveData(postParams)
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Response: ", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: ", error)
    });
}

getData(){
  this.myService.getData();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the service. Props.

Answer (score 0):

Tonye

You can store the data in localStorage.
Take a look in this link:
https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2018/03/how-to-store-and-use-data-globally-in.html

Answer (score -1):

Try storing it in the storage and get it from storage anywhere in your app.

In your first page

```
// set it in storage
setData() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

In your second page

```
// get it from storage
// create account variable where you will pass the data
account: any;

getData() {
    this.account = window.localStorage.getItem('account');

    //check on how you will access the username
    console.log(this.account);
}
```

Comment: if I want to display it in html, will it be {{account.username}} or just {{username}}?

Comment: {{ account.username }}

Comment: It displayed this error: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: what storage are you using? I recommend to use `Storage` from `@ionic/storage`. Import it to your pages. And change `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` to `.get()` and `.set()`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: window.localStorage

Comment: I edited my answer if you are using `window.localStorage`